# Url rewrites for outbound requests made by 3rd party dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, interceptor, grpc

I have a spring boot webapp that makes use of a third party dependency that is doing some grpc requests on my behalf.

As some of the urls used by that library are invalid in my environment, is it possible for me to intercept all calls made by that library and change some of the urls it uses?
Is there a way to intercept/redirect all http traffic initiated by my application?

Comment: Maarten, you have been an SO member for 5 years, so you know the game: Where is your code? Please provide the code you have problems with and describe what you tried. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kriegaex This is not a 'please fix my malconfigured code for me' question. I don't mind reading manuals, docs, source code, ... to find those kind of answers myself. This is a more of a general question. I am asking if what I want (rewriting urls of all outbound http connections) is even possible. And if so, what tool/technology/software I could use to achieve such a thing.

Comment: I am just trying to provide some guidance in order to help you improve your question. It would help me and others understand your abstract problem description better and greatly improve your chance to get meaningful answers. You could provide code reproducing your situation, then somebody could directly take and spice up that code with the tool or technology you are looking for.

Comment: As it is, the question seems off-topic to me according to the [help center description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._